# Can a new Android activity be created using an existing layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

It seems that a new layout must be created when a new Android activity is created with the wizard in Eclipse.  Whenever I create a new Android activity using an existing layout, I have to create a dummy layout, change the layout in onCreate() with setContentView(), then delete the dummy layout.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you copy an existing Activity and paste it as new Activity in eclipse instead of using wizard always?

Comment: If I do that, I will have to modify AndroidManifest.xml manually. I feel it will not be any better.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that part.  :-)

Comment: @Wand: Thank you for trying to help out here anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited Post:** If you click File > New > Other, you can choose "Android > Android Activity".
Click next, and fill in the right data. If you reach the "Preview" part, you can select the changes that must be performed. I called the new activity "SecondActivity", which means the layout would file would be called "second_activity.xml". If you uncheck this file in the list, it won't create this file. Then just change your setContentView to the file you want.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just felt awful every time I created file, then deleted it.

Comment: I have tried it twice, and the wizard still creates a new layout file despite that I unchecked it.  I am wondering if it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are relying too much on eclipse wizards. Be a programmer. Right click on package add new "class" Give it a name. Extend Activity. Override onCreate methods. In set content view use the layout already created.

Edit: Here are exact instructions

Right click on you package. Click New. Select Class.

Give your class a name, click Ok.

```
package com.example.fakeapp;

public class FakeActivity {

}
```

Now extend Activity add in onCreate and onCreateOptionsMenu Use the layout that you need in set content view.

```
package com.example.fakeapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class FakeActivity extends Activity{
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other_activity); //use whatever layout you want.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Add to the manifest between the  tags dont forget to create your title in your res/strings.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fakeapp.Fakeactivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fakeactivity" >
    </activity>
```

I did not mean to sound arrogant. What i meant to say was learn what the wizard is doing so you can recreate it and not rely on it to do everything for you. If you are afraid of editing the manifest then that is something that you need to learn.

Comment: He dont want lose the facility of manifest getting updated.  Your answer  is bit arrogant.

Comment: How come you cant update the manifest yourself. Its really simple to add an activity. You can avoid creating the extra junk layout and then having to delete it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions.  My intention was to find the the quickest and robust way to create new activities using existing layouts.

Comment: my method is the most direct if your not afraid of typing out your code. Ultimately you can use any layout in any activity by assigning it in setcontentview or inflating it at runtime.

Comment: I do not mind typing out code at all because I do it all day long.  I can create a new activity using an existing layout with wizard in less than 20 seconds  without worrying about inconsistency in the manifest, corresponding menu file and relevant values in strings.xml, etc. due to typo. Thank you again.